# Calculating audio gain on Android

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing

I'm trying to calculate audio gain for different Android samples in real-time. Are there any libraries that can actually achieve what GainNode in Javascript does 
(https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GainNode)?

I'm working with the Android visualizer so I have time domain as well as frequency domain samples available.